# How to remove some past duplicate git commits?

Tags: git, github

In my office, I found that I had committed a sensitive file to github. So I used [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://help.github.com/en/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository) to remove the file from past commits. So it was deleted and I was happy. I guess that the commit hashes were changed at that time.

I went to home and opened a github desktop. It said I need to pull from origin and I did. There were no problems until then.

But then github desktop said I have to push 3 commits. It was weird but I was curious so I agreed to push. I shouldn't have done this. Now all commits have duplicates.

It's like this (recent commit on top):

```
5 min ago : Merge branch 'master' of https:....
3 hrs ago : commit 3
22 hrs ago : commit 2
22 hrs ago : commit 2
00 days ago : commit 1
00 days ago : commit 1
00 days ago : initial commit
```

'commit 1' and 'commit 2' have duplicates.
Also one commit of 'commit 1's, one commit of 'commit 2's and 'Merge branch ...' have the sensitive file which I deleted. It was re-uploaded from github desktop right now.

I need to remove three commits without touching other commits.

Comment: After running bfg-repo cleaner, did you do a `push force`? I am afraid you pulled in your sensitive file from your remote again.

Comment: @k0pernikus Precisely because he *didn't* do a push force, he got his current situation. He should've used a push force, but instead he pulled, as you said, his sensitive files back into the repository.

Comment: I really don't like giving recommendations on stack overflow about force-pushing or stripping commits, invariably people don't understand exactly what they're doing and quite often they end up in a worse situation than they had before. However, what you probably need to do is something like `git reset --hard HASH-OF-LAST-GOOD-COMMIT` (ie. tip of the cleaned branch, before you pulled, hash of "commit 3" without sensitive data) and then `git push -f`. But, if you have made other commits in the meantime you need to do something completely different.

Comment: Either way, make sure you have a good backup of your repository, sensitive data and all, so that no matter what you do you will not end up losing everything.

Comment: Thanks everyone. For future reference, I used `git push` after applying BFG cleaner - I should have used `git push -f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best one I can think of is to use `rebase` here to rewrite the history and the do a `push force`. Following are some of the steps which can help here:

```
$> git rebase -i HEAD~6 // takes in 6 commits you want to edit

// Update the ones which you want to drop
drop xxxxxx initial commit
pick xxxxxx commit 1
drop xxxxxx commit 1
pick xxxxxx commit 2
drop xxxxxx commit 2
pick xxxxxx commit 3
drop xxxxxx Merge branch 'master' of https:....
```

> Note: The commits are listed in the opposite order than you normally
>   see them using the `log` command.

More detailed instructions [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Changing-Multiple-Commit-Messages).

Comment: It is weird but 'git log' command gives me four commits but github shows seven commits.. is this even possible?

Comment: Are the remote and local repositories in sync?

Comment: Thanks to everyone but this answer is the simplest and it worked well.

Comment: For future reference, `git rebase -i --root` will open the `git-rebase-todo` file through the editor(Visual Studio Code for me). Then you can choose which commits you want to pick.

pick xxxxxxx Initial commit
drop xxxxxxx commit 1
drop xxxxxxx commit 2
pick xxxxxxx commit 1
pick xxxxxxx commit 2
pick xxxxxxx commit 3
drop xxxxxxx Merge branch ...

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be exactly what you're looking for here:["recently made duplicate commits help"](https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Recently-made-a-duplicate-commit/td-p/5921)

EDITED: I think the above link is better for your situation since your commit_ID's may be the same. If the ID's arent though, I dont see why this wouldnt work.

also this may be something of use: [Githubs help on undoing a commit](https://gist.github.com/gunjanpatel/18f9e4d1eb609597c50c2118e416e6a6)

maybe running the prompts listed here could undo the commits you'd like to get rid of.

Running this: "git revert {commit_id}", and using the commits ID you'd like to get rid of may work. Howeve

There is also a section on undoing your last commit, but it sounds like you need to undo 3. Be sure to have a backup just in case!

Answer (score 1):

In this case, your local branch was most likely in the original (pre-cleaned) state, and the remote branch was in the altered state. After rewriting the history, you should delete any local copies, or reset the local branch to the remote one. However, now you'll need to do some cleanup yourself.

### My local was clean, the remote was not

If you cleaned your local branch, you ended up like this:

```
M─┐ eeeee Merge branch 'master' of ...
│ o ddddd Original Commit 2
│ o ccccc Original Commit 1
o │ bbbbb Commit 3
o │ aaaaa Cleaned Commit 2
o │ 99999 Cleaned Commit 1
o─┘ 88888 Previous Commit
```

Here, you need to get rid of `99999` and `aaaaa`. You could do this with an interactive rebase as with [nitishagar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56935038/283078), or you can do it by resetting your branch:

```
git reset --hard bbbbb
git push --force origin master
```

### The remote was clean, my local was not

If you cleaned up the remote, your history probably looks like this:

```
M─┐ eeeee Merge branch 'master' of ...
│ o ddddd Commit 3
│ o ccccc Original Commit 2
│ o bbbbb Original Commit 1
o │ aaaaa Cleaned Commit 2
o │ 99999 Cleaned Commit 1
o─┘ 88888 Previous Commit
```

In this case, `aaaaa` was the previous `origin/master`, and `ddddd` was your local branch. What you want to end up with is:

```
  o ddddd Commit 3
o─┘ aaaaa Cleaned Commit 2
o   99999 Cleaned Commit 1
o   88888 Previous Commit
```

You can do this with a single rebase (you can even add `-i` to confirm it's doing what you expect):

```
 git checkout master
 git rebase --onto aaaaa ddddd^
 git push --force origin master
```

This can be used no matter how many commits you've put on top of your local branch; you can refer to `ccccc` directly (the most recent local commit you want to remove), or `ddddd^` (the parent commit of the first commit you want to keep).

### Warning - force push to master

Be aware that you're rewriting history to master branch again. Given that your original commits contain the sensitive file, and you were previously happy to rewrite master's history to get rid of this, it's presumably OK for you to do it again. Just make sure to let any other users of this repository know the situation.

Comment: It is weird but 'git log' command gives me four commits but github shows seven commits.. is this even possible?

Comment: If `master` and `origin/master` are the same ID, they have the same commits. Perform a `git fetch origin` followed by `git rev-parse master` and `git rev-parse origin/master` to compare. Then look at `git log --graph master` and `git log --graph origin/master`. I also find [tig](https://jonas.github.io/tig/) to be particularly useful for viewing git history.

Comment: Thanks I've found out that origin/master and master are different in my case. I thought those are always identical..

Comment: In a non-distributed world like Subversion, there is no distinction between remote and local like this. In git, remote branches can differ from their local equivalent in just the same way as two local branches can be different from each other. In fact, a `git pull` is essentially the same as merging the remote branch into the local branch — e.g. `git fetch && git merge @{upstream}` — as you have just discovered.